# After getting married without signing the papers, and moving on and reuniting, are we still married?

Tags: nikah

I am I English woman who converted, and me and my Muslim partner had a Muslim man from the mosque come to get us married, but we never signed the papers due to my name needing to be changed.

Does this mean we are married?

We also had a daughter but split shortly after. I did move on and slept with someone he swears blind he didn't. We've now got the question because we want to be together can we get married.

Answer (score 2):

Well i guess we will still need more information, as your story has too many aspects, but i'll try to give an answer and ask questions to help you elaborate!

- Some scholars (if not most) won't accept a marriage without at least two witnesses as there is a Hadith in Musnad Ahamad, saying

> “There is no marriage except with a *Waly*, and two witnesses. The marriage is void otherwise. If they conflict, the Sultan is the Waly for whomever there is no Waly.”

but the more known hadith on the matter is [this](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/11/22), which you may find in many hadith collections.

- According to hanafi school a divorced woman can marry herself. This is based on interpretation of this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/11/29).
- You didn't mention if this was your situation before your supposed marriage ceremony! Have their been a 'Aqd an-Nikah this means did the men from the mosque write down some marriage conditions of both of you have their been a mahr declared...? Was a Waly necessary if so then your marriage would be invalid, but as you were non-muslim before i wouldn't like to give an adjudication as i'm far away of being a scholar as it could be possible that if you had a boyfriend before this could be regarded to the situation of a divorced woman.

So -*to me*- it's still unclear whether you are/were married or not. 
But why didn't you ask your supposed Muslim Husband about this (marriage papers)? Haven't you registered or done a civil marriage later or before this (supposing you are in England)?

- Supposing you were married there's an other problem you said you separated, so was this a divorce (did your supposed husband say you are divorced and left or have you left him after that?)?
- If a divorce has been spoken out you will need to wait until your *waiting period* ends before getting married again.

So this point must also be cleared before you get married (again?).

- On the other hand you said you slept with somebody. As this is regarded as a sin you and this men should repent before going ahead. This would mean that you both shouldn't meet as you are mahram for each other unless he can marry you or ask your hand in marriage.

So please try to answer my questions and feel free to ask to help us elaborate an answer.

And as an advise please be sure not to make the same mistake again if you got married again let the 'Aqd an-Nikah be written and have a copy, have if necessary a civil marriage. And try to be a good muslim!

And Allah knows best!